# How to reenable Nouveau after uninstalling NVIDIA proprietary drivers?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

**Problem:**
My Nvidia graphics card requires `340.x` drivers, so I tried installing an older-than-most-recent driver to see if it could help me. It did not help, and now I that I removed it, I cannot get any other resolution on my screen, besides `1024 x 768`.

**Steps taken:**

1. `apt install nvidia-legacy-390xx-driver` (old, but not enough);
2. `apt remove nvidia-drivers` (too newer than 340);
3. `apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx` because [someone on the internet said it would work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360761/cannot-get-rid-of-nvidia-drivers-restore-nouveau-driver-and-get-desktop-working).
4. `apt install nvidia-drivers`
5. `apt remove nvidia-smi`
6. `apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx` again, because [someone on the internet still says it would work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360761/cannot-get-rid-of-nvidia-drivers-restore-nouveau-driver-and-get-desktop-working).

This did not restore the resolution to the normal that I used before. On the settings through GUI, I can only set `1024 x 768`.

How to fix Nouveau on Debian 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Use this command to remove all packages from the package cache, so new ones will have to be downloaded: `sudo apt-get clean`
> 2. Remove the existing Nvidia driver installation: `sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*`
> 3. Reboot

**Source:** [roblm on Linux Mint Forums, 10 years ago](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=341313&sid=929a08565c671ca7f1decb12bf9aa380&start=20).

Now the resolution could be *extremely* upgraded from `1024 x 768` to `1366 x 768`, which is the native resolution of this 12 yo monitor.